# QT Creator 3.0.1 Debugging On Windows Suddenly Becomes Slow. Why?

Tags: windows, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I've been using QT Creator 3.0.1 on Windows fine for a long time and now, all of a sudden, debugging is incredibly slow. Stepping over, seeing locals in the watch window, resuming execution, everything takes many minutes to work. If I hit a breakpoint or crash and try to step over, I see the message "Run requested..." and then nothing for a long time. The normal debugging UI is disabled (pause, stop, etc) but the stop button in the Application Output window is enabled and works.

Details on my setup:

- Running on Windows XP SP3 32bit
- Using kit Desktop 5.2.1 MSVC2010 32bit
- cdb.exe from Debugging Tools for Windows x86
- using the default symbol cache location and server that QT Creator gives me.

I've deleted and recreated the symbol cache, repaired the Debugging Tools for Windows install but nothing changed.

What could be causing this? Are there files or folders that need to be cleaned, cleared, reset?

Comment: Have you checked if the application is leaking memory or the one that you debug?

Comment: The problem appears even at the start of execution. If I put a breakpoint at the first line of main, still happens. Also, I've restarted QT Creator and my machine several times, just to be safe. No change.

Comment: Just noticed: It takes less time for the debugger to become responsive again at the breakpoint at the first line of main(). After that, it seems to work fine again. But if I remove it, the original problem is still there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the watch window. I had two variables I had entered manually in the watch window. For some reason, having them totally kills the debugger performance.

Simply removing them from the watch window didn't seem to work, though. I had to manually remove them from the default.qws file. The file is located in c:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\QtProject\qtcreator\default.qws.

I found a node "value-Watchers" containing my two variables and removed the whole Data section that contained them. After that, debugging performance was back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same issue, and resolved by clearing all the user settings folders.
According to the Qt documentation the locations are as follows with respect to the platform

- On Linux and other Unix platforms, the files are located in
  `~/.config/QtProject` and `~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator`.
- On macOS, the files are located in `~/.config/QtProject` and
  `~/Library/Application Support/QtProject/Qt Creator`.
- On Windows XP,the files are located in `%SystemDrive%\Documents` and
  `Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\QtProject` and
  `%SystemDrive%\Documents` and `Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\QtProject`
- On Windows 7, the files are
  located in `%SystemDrive%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\QtProject`
  and `%SystemDrive%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\QtProject`.

source:http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html#location-of-settings-files

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Usually it would take 10 seconds to load the debugger and it went to 10 minutes. **I renamed the file default.qws and it worked.** Analyzing deeper I found out that the **problem is with the breakpoints**: if a breakpoint is on a file which is not part of the project, the debugger attempts to resolve the breakpoint for each loaded module/DLL, making the process incredibly slow.

The solution is to edit the file default.qws and remove those breakpoints which are set to files that don't exists anymore.